# Spoof calling SDK for native iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call, spoofing, spoof

Hello is there any API or SDK available for spoof call function in iOS ? As I need functionality where dialer add his own number and receiver number. The receiver will receive call from those number which added by the dialer (spoof number/ any number).

Please help if someone knows.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS it's impossible to set the caller ID of a mobile call.

The only way to make a phone call from code is to open a `tel://<number-you-want-to-call>` URL.  iOS will then take over and will open the native Phone app.  Of course the SIM card's caller ID will be shown to the callee; there's no way to influence that (apart from hiding it, if your operator allows that).

If you wish to set another caller ID, you need to create a VoIP app and you need a VoIP backend that terminates the call on the telephone network.